# Join conditions and Where conditions in Left Join

Tags: join

STUDENT table contains a list of students in my school Database

LIBRARY_BOOK table contains the information of each Book that is with currently with any student.

each student is allowed only 1 book at a time.

I want to know

Library Book with each Class 7 Student.

I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2

I have few queries which looks almost similar but don't behave in same way.

Query 1 :

```
Select *
FROM STUDENT ST
LEFT JOIN LIBRARY_BOOK LB
ON ST.Student_Id = LB._Student_ID
WHERE ST.Class = 7
```

Query 2 :

```
Select *
FROM STUDENT ST
LEFT JOIN LIBRARY_BOOK LB
ON ST.Student_Id = LB._Student_ID
AND ST.Class = 7
```

Query 3 :

```
Select *
FROM STUDENT ST
LEFT JOIN LIBRARY_BOOK LB
ON ST.Student_Id = LB._Student_ID
AND ST.Class = 7
WHERE ST.Class = 7
```

Can someone explain the difference between these queries in terms of both Output and Performance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Query 1 will show you All records from `student` with a `Class` value of 7, and then any related `Library_Book` records if they exist.

Query 2 will show you all records from `student`, and related `Library_Book` records if they exist and if the matching row in `student` has a `Class` of 7.

Query 3 will show you All records from `student` with a `Class` value of 7, and related `Library_Book` records if they exist.

I would expect query 1 and query 3 will give you the same results, and query 2 to give you  more rows.

Performance is impossible to talk about without knowing your table structure, distribution of data, indexes, and RDBMS.  I would not expect them to be very different though since your filters are all the same.

Comment: In the first query, I am joining Entire table Student with Library and then fetching the class 7 results. on the other hand in query 3, I am joining only class 7 portion of Student with Library. So wont it be a relevant improvement in performance.

Comment: @PratyushDhanuka Query 3 had redundant filters, so the performance would be the same. If you filter on the same criteria twice I would expect any RDBMS to optimize one out. The extra filter in the JOIN condition is not on the JOINed table, and already exists in the `WHERE` clause so it doesn't actually matter.

Comment: Its true that query 1 and query 3 will give same output but the join condition is not redundant. You see the difference in query 3 I am only joining with class 7 records then filtering class 7 records. Where as in Query 1, I am joining entire table then filtering only class 7, here records from other classes will also be joined with Library table which I don't want as I have no need for result from other class but 7. So again I believe query 3 will have better perf. You can assume student table is indexed with student id, and have equal distribution of data over each class and clarify.

Comment: I'm confused about why you're asking a question here and then refusing to believe the answers. In Query 3 you filter on Student.Class = 7 in two separate places. The ENTIRE RESULT SET from the student table is limited to Class = 7. In the JOIN condition it's redundant because every record MUST be Student.Class = 7 since there are no other records in the result set from student table (based on the WHERE clause).

Comment: @PratyushDhanuka You said it yourself: If query 1 and query 3 always give same output, **then the join condition is redundant.** Nothing else is needed.

Comment: @PratyushDhanuka In query 1 you are not "joining the entire table **then** filtering". I mean, you wrote that code, but the optimizer isn't (necessarily) doing things in that order, and it will most certainly disregard the redundant join condition. You can see this clearly by comparing query 1 and query 3 execution plans. Remember that SQL is declarative, you tell the optimizer what you want, and it will get you the best way to do it

Comment: @JNK I am asking because I am confused about the difference between those 2 queries. I was under the understanding that first SQL will Join and based on Join result it will filter based on where, could not see any perf changes when I tried with big data so asked here.

Comment: @Lamak I saw the execution plans and seeing them for first time..could not get all but I was able to see that both queries are having same execution plan even the internal details and was able to see what you were saying, thanks for the help. Now I am more certain on how queries work